# Bending an image in SVG

Tags: javascript, image, svg, jquery-svg

In my SVG application, I have images which the user can extend. I'd like to give controls to the user so they can bend them from the edges as well.

Here is a visual example of what a user could do.

[image: Bending a lace - before & after]

Would love to hear suggestions on how to go about doing this.

One possible idea is that I put the image inside a path & add controls for stretching the edges of the path. However, I wonder how to stretch the image inside the path so that it consumes the whole available space.

Comment: Can you please clarify if this question is about the way UI should work?

Comment: maybe something in the direction of textPath X fabric.js  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve/?

Comment: @Adam No, I am thinking more about the implementation of this idea, i.e. how would I be able to bend an image in SVG. Hope this answers your que.

Comment: @MaxGherkins exactly! TextPath is an example & the fabric.js with its quadratic curve is awesome. Again, the question is how to go about implementing for an image?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do what you want.  However I can suggest two possible tricky ways:

(1) Convert it to a chain of images and apply an appropriate skew transform to each one.

(2) Use an `<feDisplacementMap>` filter to displace the pixels to the appropriate place.

Comment: (1) is not possible we previously tried that, however the calculations (our app. is already pretty heavy) of transforming a couple of tens of images (let alone a hundred in our case) can pretty much hang the app. (2) sounds interesting, am looking into this now, thanks

Comment: Re (1), I didn't mean transforming a bunch of images yourself. I was referring to using `skewY()` transforms in your SVG.

Comment: apologies for poor choice of words, I did mean skew. Im hoping to look into the fedisplacementmap filter today to see whats possible. Will post back with thoughts.